# What is P(Y) here?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, notation

A multivalued map, f: X -> Y, from a set X to a set Y, is a map f: X ->
P(Y). Multivalued maps will be also called multimaps. I don't understand what a multimap is in category theory and I think the P means power set? But I'm unsure.

Comment: Think in term of a map (function) $f : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$. A "usual" function takes as input a number and gives as output a number. A multimap $f : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ gives as output (for input $n$) an element of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, i.e. a subset of $\mathbb N$, i.e. a *set of numbers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just mean that $f(x) \subseteq Y$, i.e. the map sends $x$ to a subset of $Y$. Usually the notation $\mathcal P(Y)$ denotes the set of all subsets of $Y$. Yes, the $P$ does mean power set.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Hope that helps,

Comment: How about what a multimap is? I tried googling the term and can't find anything. Is there another phrase for it?

Comment: @yesione : I said $f(x) \subseteq Y$, i.e. $x$ maps to a subset of $Y$. Wasn't that clear? Or you're asking for a reference?

Comment: @yesione : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function

Comment: Is there a way to visualize the multimap? I actually did not know a power set was all subsets, so thanks for the wiki. In a power set do all the subsets get mapped as in "onto" or it can be just some of them?

Comment: If you have a multimap $f : \{1,2\} \to \{3,4\}$, you can have $f(1) = \{3,4\}$ and $f(2) = \varnothing$. I mean, a multimap $f : \{1,2\} \to \{3,4\}$ is nothing more than an ordinary map $f : \{1,2\} \to \{ \varnothing, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{3,4\} \}$. Set-theoretically speaking there's nothing more to it, but it can have some uses I guess probably in combinatorics or topology.